# On the issues of scaling Firebase Backend

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, scalability

I am starting development on a backend system. It will be supporting cross platform mobile apps. The backend has many functionalities which, prompted me to divide the backend into 8 services (deployed as Cloud Functions) and exposed as a REST API for clients. Each of the deployed function will be using firestore and will strictly query collections relating to that particular service. Inter service communication over HTTP is strictly prohibited and all such communications have been restricted to Cloud Messaging.

Now, I have been told recently that Firebase will be a "bottleneck" and will not be able to handle scaling. I am pretty confident that scaling will not be an issue since, scaling a service will simply mean multiplying the number of deployed function instance. The same goes for database (Firestore). From a general perspective, it is safe for me say that Firebase will be scalable? I know there are lot of challenges and it's a broad question. However, such challenges will even exist when I go for my own setup on a VPS. So, to clarify my question: from the perspective of a backend that have many services developed as REST APIs. is Firebase a scalable option? Any suggestions, references or, guidelines will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're asking about is not really about "Firebase" (which is a mobile application development platform), but more about Cloud Functions, which is a scalable serverless Google Cloud product.  Firebase just adds tools and APIs on top of the core Cloud Functions product.  Otherwise, the code deployed by the Firebase CLI behaves exactly the same as if you deployed it using Google Cloud tools.  Read more about the relationship between Firebase and Google Cloud with respect to Cloud Functions in [this article](https://medium.com/google-developers/firebase-google-cloud-whats-different-with-cloud-functions-612d9e1e89cb).

The same is true for Firestore, which is also a Google Cloud product.  It scales massively, and you can read about its [known limitations](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/quotas).  Read a [similar blog](https://medium.com/google-developers/firebase-google-cloud-whats-different-with-cloud-firestore-40f1fc3e6d1e) about the differences between Firebase and Google Cloud with respect to Firestore.

There is a good amount of documentation about how Cloud Functions scales.  For HTTP type functions, your limits are based on the volume of of data you are sending out of your function instances.  You can read about the limits in the [Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas).  Practically speaking, I've never heard of anyone exceeding the limits of Cloud Functions for the sort of work that it's meant to do (which is to say, work that is time-boxed to the max configurable 9 minute limit, at the memory limits of the class of machine being used).

Again, none of this has to do with Firebase or of any of its other, many, products.  All you need to understand is the behavior of the individual products you want to use, both of which are Google Cloud products.

Whoever told you that you'd have problems scaling with "Firebase" was probably referring to the product Firebase Realtime Database, which does have limitations that require the use of sharding if you want to scale up massively.  Firestore does not have that limitation - you don't have to do anything to scale it.

Comment: I am going through the links you attached now. Your explanation really helped me understand the concepts here and I badly needed that.